# Haskell :add a type signature that fixes these type variables(s)?

Tags: haskell, signature

I try to get symmetric difference of two lists:

such as:

```
  [1,2,3] [2,3,5]
```

the result is `[1]`

This is my code:

```
getlist _  []=[]
getlist [] _ = []
getlist (x:xs) ys = if isexist x ys
             then x++ getlist xs ys
                   else
                      getlist xs ys
isexist a [] = False
isexist a (x:xs) = if a == x
          then True
          else isexist a xs
```

There is an error:

> The type variable 'a0' is ambiguous
>   
>   Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)

What does that mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: `then x : (getlist xs ys)`?

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't actually produce any error. When asking a question, please provide sufficient information for others to reproduce the exact problem you're experiencing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the error all you have to do as @Joker_vD pointed out is to replace your `++` with `:`

To understand the difference between the two you should look at the type signature:

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

As you could see, `:` takes an element and a list and returns a list back. `++` on the other hand takes two lists.

You should look at `Data.Set` and `Data.List` packages if you want to do set intersections / diff more efficiently.

Note that after fixing the error, the program's output will not match what you wanted. You should investigate why that's happening and should be an easy fix.